# lower() and searching for a word in a file using a list

Tags: python

So what I'd like to do is to make all the lines lowercase and then use my part_list to search for all words matching in frys.txt and to append it to items. I'm having a lot of trouble creating a loop that goes through each word in the list and just actually finding the words in frys.txt. I'm even trying to find doubles if that is at all possible. But the main thing I want to be able to do is just find that the word exists and to append it to items if it does.

Any suggestions would be great!

```
items = []
part_list = ['ccs', 'fcex', '8-12', '8-15', '8-15b', '80ha3']
f = open("C:/Users/SilenX/Desktop/python/frys.txt", "r+")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()

for n, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    p = 0
    if part_list[p] in line.split():
        part_list[p] = part_list[p + 1]
        parts = searchlines[n]
        parts = parts.strip('\n')
        items.append(parts)

print items
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing some complex stuff with enumeration that I really don't think is necessary, and it definitely looks like your inner "loop" isn't doing what you want (because as you've written it, it isn't a loop). Try this:

```
part_list = ['ccs', 'fcex', '8-12', '8-15', '8-15b', '80ha3']
items = []
f = open("C:/Users/SilenX/Desktop/python/frys.txt", "r") # Open the file
for line in f:
    for token in line.lower().split(): # Loop over lowercase words in the line
        if token in part_list: # If it's one of the words you're looking for,
            items.append(token) # Append it to your list.
f.close()
print items
```

This will find all the words in the file that appear in your list. It **will not** identify words in your file that are attached to something else, like `"ccs."` or `"fcex8-12"`. If you want that, you'll have to reverse the way the search works, so that you count how many times each word in `part_list` appears in the line rather than counting how many words in the line are in `part_list`.

Comment: Wow! That's so much simpler. Thank you so much.